# Does this creates variables with respective sizes as written after colon?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, sizeof, bit-fields

I'm going through some code involving lots of structures and enums, for the first time. So I am facing some issues in understanding. There is some register initialization using struct?

```c
struct register_name
{
uint32_t var1:10;
uint32_t var2:22;
};
```

does it create var1 and var2 with 10-bits and 22 bits? (register is of 32 bit)

Comment: Yes. The `var1` field will hold the first 10 bits, and the `var2` field the remaining 22.

Comment: Yes, it is allocating 2 unsigned bitfields of widths 10 and 22 from a 32-bit wide allocation unit. Note that this sort of thing is not very portable as some compilers allocate from the top end of the allocation unit downwards, and other compilers allocate from the bottom end of the allocation unit upwards. And that is not related to whether the architecture is big-endian or little-endian.

Comment: Best practice is to avoid bit fields entirely.

Comment: the best detail to remember is that the order of the bit fields, with the 32 bit area is implementation defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler does not create internally two objects of the sizes 10 and 22. Internally it creates one object of the size 32 and splits it into two parts interpretating them as var1 and var2.

The compiler provides a posiibility by which you have an ability to control how many objects will be created internally.

Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct A
{
    uint32_t var1:10;
    uint32_t var2:22;
};

struct B
{
    uint32_t var1:10;
    uint32_t : 0;
    uint32_t var2:22;
};

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "sizeof( struct A ) = %zu\n", sizeof( struct A ) );
    printf( "sizeof( struct B ) = %zu\n", sizeof( struct B ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
sizeof( struct A ) = 4
sizeof( struct B ) = 8
```

In case of the structure B each variable `var1` and `var2` is contained as a part in own internal object of the size equal to 32.

Logically the `var1` and `var2` indeed occupy 10 and 22 bits correspondingly. The compiler does all the work under the hood.

Comment: (a) Bit-fields are objects in the C standard. For bit-fields, it says “The object representation is the set of *m* bits of the bit-field comprises in the addressable storage unit holding it.” (C 2018 6.2.6.2 4.) In numerous places, it distinguishes bit-fields from other objects, as by saying “Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of…” The definition of “object” as a region of data storage in 3.15 does not limited it to addressable units.

Comment: (b) The storage unit used to hold a bit-field is not necessarily 32 bits, even if the `int` or register size is 32 bits; an implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit. (c) It is implementation-defined whether a following bit-field is, if it fits, packed into the same unit.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Logically the compiler considers bit-fields as objects but phisically they are parts of fundamental objects.